# TypeScript React infer function argument from passed prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, typescript-types

I am trying to replace `any` type in the code below to something that will allow me to type the `value` of the `onSelected` function based on what type was passed as the `value` in the `items` array so I dont lose typesafety in the callback.

```
interface DropdownProps {
    items: {
        value: any;
        title: string;
    }[];
    defaultSelected?: number;
    onSelected: (value: DropdownProps["items"][number]["value"]) => void;
}
```

I tried adding `<T>` to `DropdownProps`, but then TS requires to provide something instead of `T` the component type.

```
interface DropdownProps<T> {
    items: {
        value: T;
        title: string;
    }[];
    defaultSelected?: number;
    onSelected: (value: DropdownProps<T>["items"][number]["value"]) => void;
}

export const Dropdown: React.FC<DropdownProps< here >> = (props) => { ... }
```

Comment: you will have to avoid using `React.FC` in that case. You may try:`export const Dropdown = <T>(props: Props<T>): ReactNode => {}`

Comment: There's no point repeating your title as the first sentence of your question (and there **is** a point in not doing so, both in terms of what people see in the list of questions, and in terms of not irritating the people you're asking for help).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, i think it got merged there automatically by StackOverflow though

Comment: @wonderflame, could you elaborate? this doesnt seem to be recognised as valid syntax if i write it like that
`export const Dropdown = <T>(DropdownProps<T>):ReactNode => { ... }`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that `<T>` is considered as JSX because of the `.tsx` file, just add `,` after `T`: `<T,>`. Like in [here](https://tsplay.dev/W46QvN)

Comment: @wonderflame, ok, now the typing in the component works, but if i pass an array of items like this
`const languages = [{ title: "EN", value: "en" }, { title: "RU", value: "ru" },];`
the type of `value` in the callback function is `unknown` instead of `string`

Comment: can you include a playground link where you get `unknown`?

Comment: @wonderflame the [playground](https://tsplay.dev/NaDZyw) works, but I'm getting `unknown`  for some [reason](https://prnt.sc/ojhjzxUa_Yug)

Comment: can you make sure that playground has the same tsconfig options as your env does?

Comment: @wonderflame tried to recreate the `unknown` [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/adoring-sanderson-qwqeqs), the tsconfig doesnt seem to be the issue

Comment: The only difference i see is that my env recognises `<Dropdown />` as `const Dropdown: React.ComponentType<DropdownProps<unknown>>` and the sandbox recognises it as `const Dropdown: <T>(props: DropdownProps<T>) => React.JSX.Element`

Comment: Found the issue, i was importing the Dropdown with `next/dynamic`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the types as per @wonderflame 's comment gives typing on the type of `value` in the `onSelected` function

```
interface DropdownProps<T> {
    items: {
        title: string;
        value: T;
    }[];
    defaultSelected?: number;
    onSelected: (value: DropdownProps<T>["items"][number]["value"]) => void;
}

export const Dropdown = <T,>(props: DropdownProps<T>) => { ... }
```